# difference between 'kill -INT pid' and 'kill pid' when process is in the middle of writing to a file

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix, command

I am running a python script at a specified time and stopping it at another specified time. Both of these tasks are done using cron.

The python script's job is to write a piece of text to a text file (say every 5 seconds). At a certain time, the second cron job will occur which will stop the python script from running. My goal is to see the output of the python script within the text file after the second cron job has stopped the running python program (at the specified time).

At first I tried the following command: `kill $(pgrep -f cron_test.py)`

However, I found that whenever I looked at the contents of the text file upon ending the python script, nothing would be written to it.

I then tried the following command as a replacement: `kill -INT $(pgrep -f cron_test.py)`

This command seems to have worked in allowing me to stop the python program from running, while writing to the file as well.

**I don't understand why the replacement command allows me to write to the file, while the initial command I tried does not. Any help is appreciated.**

Comment: `kill -INT pid` sends a SIGINT signal, `kill pid` on the other hand sends a SIGTERM.

Answer (score 0):

`kill` sends a signal to a process. The most common signals are:

```
       Signal        x86/ARM     Alpha/   MIPS   PARISC   Notes
                   most others   SPARC
       ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       SIGHUP           1           1       1       1
       SIGINT           2           2       2       2
       SIGQUIT          3           3       3       3
       SIGILL           4           4       4       4
       SIGTRAP          5           5       5       5
       SIGABRT          6           6       6       6
       SIGIOT           6           6       6       6
       SIGBUS           7          10      10      10
       SIGEMT           -           7       7      -
       SIGFPE           8           8       8       8
       SIGKILL          9           9       9       9
       SIGUSR1         10          30      16      16
       SIGSEGV         11          11      11      11
       SIGUSR2         12          31      17      17
       SIGPIPE         13          13      13      13
       SIGALRM         14          14      14      14
       SIGTERM         15          15      15      15
```

The default is SIGTERM, so `kill $(pgrep -f cron_test.py)` is the same as `kill -15 $(pgrep -f cron_test.py)`

A script (or any program for that matter) may choose to catch a signal. An example script in Python:

```
import signal
import os
import time


def receiveSignal(signalNumber, frame):
    print('Received:', signalNumber)
    print ("Oh dear, someone just signaled me")
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # register the signals to be caught
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, receiveSignal)

print('My PID is:', os.getpid())


while True:
    print('Waiting...')
    time.sleep(3)
```

So, it is likely that your script has a specific handler for SIGINT, which gracefully shuts-down the program, writing the output etc.